# Get the smallest element of a kdtree

Tags: java, kdtree

I want to get the minimum element of a kdtree two-dimensional (x, y).
The minimum element is one that for every element (x ', y') of kdtree, x

As can be repeated elements x, returns either.

Comment: Seems like I'm reading Truncated Data.

Comment: What did you try already? I think your question is incomplete as the condition for minimum is missing. Forgot to copy/paste that from the assignment?

Comment: I have a method minimum () that calls another recursive method minimoRec (Node n), with n equal to the root node, which compares key elements of the right subtree.

They do not work as I want, and running through the tree until you find leaf nodes (left or right without children), and once you find them compared

Comment: I have two books describing k-d trees but they do not conver the min() operation. Who needs the minimum element, that usually is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about finding the nearest point to (-BIG_NUMBER,-BIG_NUMBER)?